# Check if at least one of two values exist and are not empty

Tags: python, dictionary

The best solution I have now. Not pythonic enough for most people, I would hope!

```
# First Check if at least one of the two values exist in the OrderedDict.
if 'content' in validated_data or 'location' in validated_data:

    # If one exists, make sure it is not empty
    if 'content' in validated_data:
        if not validated_data['content']:
            raise MyException("You cannot have blank values")
    if 'location' in validated_data:
        if not validated_data['location']:
            raise MyException("You cannot have blank values")
    return validated_data

raise MyException("You need at least one field")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dict.get()` to return a default value if a key is missing; use this to test for *both* keys and values:

```
if not (validated_data.get('content') or validated_data.get('location')):
    raise MyException("You need at least one non-blank field")
return validated_data
```

If `validated_data['content']` exists, `validated_data.get('content')` will return it. If it does *not* exist, `None` is returned instead, a false value. So both when the key exists but is false, and when the key is missing, the end result is a false value and the `'location'` key is tested. If the key exists and is not a false value, the `or` expression short-circuits.

Comment: You, sir, are an animal!